# Link another account with oauth on passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js, docusignapi

Context:

- 1 spa
- 1 api
- 1 existing passport strategy with jwt

Feature:

- Connect additional account with oauth to the existing account

I already have an authentification using passport on nodejs.
This generates a jwt allowing the users to authenticate them with a bearer token in the header of each request to the api.

I would like to add an additional oauth connection to the existing account (actually it is docusign but I think the problem could be the same with other connections).

When there is the redirection with the authorization code, I cannot identify the user which has initiated the connection because I don't have the bearer token in the request header anymore and the data between the two accounts can be different (different emails for example).

Is there a workaround for this or did I miss something?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport has an [`Authorize`](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authorize/) method which can be used to authenticate with a secondary IdP. For example:

1. Use Passport#Login to enable the user to login to your application's primary IdP
2. Use Passport#Authorize to enable the user to authenticate with a secondary IdP (such as DocuSign) as needed.

Regarding state for your redirect method (determining which IdP should be used to exchange the authorization code for an access token):

1. You can use the state parameter that is sent as part of the OAuth authorization code grant flow. But be sure to also use the parameter as a random nonce to guard against a CSRF attack. Eg, send `idp1|random_nonce` so you can both check the nonce and know that you should communicate with idp1, not idp2.
2. You can use your application's session machinery to maintain your app's state knowledge of which IdP you're working with at the time.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Your suggestion worked well: using a token in the state parameter  with an expiration time and usable once.

Comment: Hi, how can I apply this with nestjs and typescript decorators?

Answer (score 1):

The only one I can think of is having 2 apps. Each can run on a different port or vd. Each would have their own passport strategy. The two apps can redirect to eachother and/or communicate using API endpoints to pass data between them.